# ParametricNDSolve with more functions

Tags: differential-equations

A MWE of my problem is this:

```
Clear[k]
Ssol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{D[h00[t], {t, 2}] == -k h22[t], 
   D[h22[t], {t, 2}] == -k h00[t], h00[0.4] == 0, h00[0.99999] == 0, 
   h22[0.4] == 0, h22[0.99999] == 0}, {h00, h22}, {t, 0.4, 0.99999}, 
  k]
```

This code evaluates (it seems) producing the following:

[image]

On the other hand the following code:

```
k = 1;
{S1, S2} = 
 NDSolveValue[{D[h00[t], {t, 2}] == -k h22[t], 
   D[h22[t], {t, 2}] == -k h00[t], h00[0.4] == 0, h00[0.99999] == 0, 
   h22[0.4] == 0, h22[0.99999] == 0}, {h00, h22}, {t, 0.4, 0.99999}]
Plot[{S1[t], S2[t]}, {t, 0.4, 0.9}]
```

produces a result with two functions which I can plot:

[image]

I expect that `ParametricNDSolveValue` to produce two interpolating functions, but it produces only one. It seems that `ParametricNDSolveValue` sees the two functions `h00,h22` as one: how can I access to the solution for both functions? Or how can I fix my code?

If needed I use M. 11.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ParametricNDSolve` evaluates two interpolation-objects depending on the parameter `k`.

```
Ssol[1]
(* {Interpolation[...],Interpolation[...]} *)
```

Try

```
Through[Ssol[1][t]]
```

to get the tw0 interpolationfunctions!